# Camel 2.10 change blueprint.xml location

Tags: java, apache-camel, osgi, blueprint-osgi

Is there an way to change the blueprint.xml file location? In my application, camel look for this on classpath and "OSGI-INF\blueprint" folder, but I want to point its reference to another file outside this folder (just like a second blueprint.xml option).

I've tried the "fileApplicationContextUri" option on camel-maven-plugin plugin inside my pom.xml, but it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should state the alternative location of your Blueprint file in **Bundle-Blueprint** header in the manifest file:

> Bundle-Blueprint: lib/account.xml, security.bp, cnf/*.xml

Comment: Absolutely correct. It would be worth backing this up with a specifcation reference: section 121.3.4 of the OSGi Compendium states that the list of XML resources is defined by the `Bundle-Blueprint` header and that the default value for that header is `OSGI-INF/blueprint/*.xml`.